# Error when including .hpp files for VCL Style Utils generated in Embarcadero C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo, vcl-styles.-utils

I want to use the library "VCL Style Utils" in Embarcadero C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo.

So I created a new project and added:

```
Vcl.Styles.Utils.Graphics.pas
Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus.pas
Vcl.Styles.Utils.SysControls.pas
Vcl.Styles.Utils.SysStyleHook.pas
```

The build is successful and generates `.hpp` files for these `.pas` files.

Then I create another project and include the `.hpp` files generated.

But when building I get this error:

> [bcc32 Error] Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus.hpp(164): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly.

Here are lines 163 and 164 of Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus.hpp :

```
static const System::Word MN_SETHMENU = System::Word(0x1e0);
static const System::Word MN_GETHMENU = System::Word(0x1e1);
```

Why are these declarations incorrect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely pre-existing `#define` statements for `MN_SETHMENU` and `MN_GETHMENU` in another C/C++ header file that is in scope, eg:

```
#define MN_SETHMENU 0x01E0
#define MN_GETHMENU 0x01E1
```

If so, that would interfere with the declarations generated in `Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus.hpp`, making the compiler see them as:

```
static const System::Word 0x01E0 = System::Word(0x1e0);
static const System::Word 0x01E1 = System::Word(0x1e1);
```

Which is clearly wrong, and hence the errors.

In `Vcl.Styles.Utils.Menus.pas` (and in `.pas` files in general), the declarations for `MN_SETHMENU` and `MN_GETHMENU` (and anything else that is already pre-defined in C/C++ headers) need to be marked with the [`{$EXTERNALSYM ...}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/External_Symbols_(Delphi)) directive so they are not re-declared in the generated `.hpp` file, eg:

```
{$EXTERNALSYM MN_SETHMENU} // <-- add this
MN_SETHMENU = $01E0;

{$EXTERNALSYM MN_GETHMENU} // <-- add this
MN_GETHMENU = $01E1;
```

If necessary, use the [`{$HPPEMIT '...'}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/HPP_emit_(Delphi)) directive to add suitable `#include` statements to the generated `.hpp` file so it can pull in other C/C++ header files as needed, eg:

```
{$HPPEMIT '#include <OtherFile.h>'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm not sure how to use EXTERNALSYM. I tried `{$EXTERNALSYM  MN_SETHMENU}`. Without then with keeping the declaration `'MN_SETHMENU = $01E0;`. And without then with uncommenting these lines : `{$IF CompilerVersion >= 27}` // uncomment these lines if you want to use the VCL Styles Menus Hooks `{$UNDEF UseVCLStyleUtilsMenu}` // included on XE6-XE8  (Embarcadero Version) // `{$IFEND}`

Comment: I tried this too: adding `{$HPPEMIT  #include <Vcl.SysStyles.hpp>}` but i'm not sure of the pascal pre-processor syntax and it gives the error `E1030 Invalid compiler directive`.

Comment: @Arnaud I updated my answer to show how to use `EXTERNALSYM`. And you don't need to use `HPPEMIT` to include other VCL headers, any unit specific in the `uses` clause of the `interface` section is automatically converted into an `#include` statement.

Comment: Thank you Remy. With the $EXTERNALSYM as you updated it the declaration are not in the `.hpp`.